# C++: if swap is callled in another function, why it cannot work

Tags: c++, function, pointers, swap

I'm curious why operation2 can succssfully exchange `a` and `b`, while operation1 cannot.

```
//operation1:
void exchange(char *a, char *b)
{swap(a,b);}

//operation2:
swap(a,b);
```

(I've condensed my entire code into a few lines above)

I realize operation1 is kind of nonsense, but still, I'm wondering why it cannot work.

Comment: Since you're not passing the pointers by references the swap occurs on `a` and `b` which are unique to that that scope.

Comment: Also, don't use `exchange` as name, because we have already ```myVar = std::exchange(myOldVar`, "value-for-old-var");```

Answer (score 5):

You are swapping local variables `a` and `b`, which are being passed in **by value**, thus they are *copies* of the caller's variables. The caller's original variables are left unaffected.

To update the caller's variables, you need to pass them in **by reference** instead:

```
void exchange(char* &a, char* &b) {
    swap(a, b);
}

...

exchange(a, b);
```

Or, pass them in **by pointer** instead:

```
void exchange(char **a, char **b) {
    swap(*a, *b);
}

...

exchange(&a, &b);
```